# Find probability of event

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Task is: **Find probability of 4 aces laying in row in a deck of 36 cards.**

All possible shufflings of 36 deck is $36!$ I can place 4 cards in a row with $33$ different ways. And each way can be $4!$ altered because, we don't care in what order 4 aces are.

So probability is: $$\frac{33\cdot4!}{36!}$$

Answer does not match with answer in a book. Where am I wrong? Thank you!

[EDIT]

Book's answer is $\frac{1}{1785}$

[/EDIT]

Comment: The last part of your question, starting with "and each way can be $4!$ altered...". Could you clarify?

Comment: We place 4 cards in a row, in 36 cards deck with 36-4+1 way. But, every way of placing 4 cards can be altered 4! ways by swapping places of aces in this 4 cards.

Comment: What is the book's answer?

Comment: For the (adjacent) aces there are $4!$ possibilities when it comes to orderings. For the other cards there are $32!$ possibilities as well. I suspect the answer in the book is $\frac{33.4!32!}{36!}=33\binom{36}{4}^{-1}$

Comment: @drhab Yes, you are right!

Comment: @drhab Can you kindly explain me, why we should consider $32!$ possibilities for other cards, even if we are not interested in their position at all?

Comment: Well, why do you consider $36!$ ways (in the denominator) if you are only interested in the position of the  $4$ aces? Numerator and denominator must be treated the same way.

Comment: @drhab Thank you, I'll think about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placing $36$ cards in a row can be done on $36!$ ways. If we add the condition that the first $4$ cards are aces then it can be done on $4!32!$ ways. If we add the weaker condition that the aces must be adjacent then it can be done on $33.4!32!$ ways. So there is a probability of: $$\frac{33.4!32!}{36!}=\frac1{1785}$$ that it happens.

Comment: Can you kindly explain me, why we should consider 32! possibilities for other cards, even if we are not interested in their position at all?

Comment: Well, why do you consider $36!$ ways (in the denominator) if you are only interested in the position of the  $4$ aces? Numerator and denominator must be treated the same way.

Comment: @DoctorMoisha Precisely because you're not interested in their posititons. In other words, you accept all possible configurations of them, and the probability is the accepted cases/all cases. Just like you multiplied by 4! because you don't care about the order of those. You don't want one specific order, all 4! orders are okay. Also for the other cards, all orders are okay.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is the number of ways to place $4$ cards in a row. I assume this is $4$ cards out of the deck of $36$.

There are $36$ choices for the first card, then $35$ for the second (since the first is no longer available), then $34$ for the third, then $33$ for the fourth. Thus the number of ways to choose $4$ cards out of the deck of $36$ and place them in a row is

$$36\cdot 35\cdot 34\cdot 33=\frac{36!}{32!}$$

The last part of your question is not clear. Could you clarify?

Comment: It will be right if we place them not in row, but if we place 4 cards in a row, we have 36 - 4 + 1 ways to place them. Or not?

Comment: @DoctorMoisha: Not. Although I still do not understand what you mean. My calculation means taking one card from the deck, placing it down, choosing a second from the remaining deck, placing it down, and so on. In this method, the order of the cards counts. If the order does not count, the number is ${36 \choose 4}$.

Comment: Sorry, English is not my first language. Yes, I understand what you say, but it is ways of taking any 4 cards from 36 cards deck. I mean, we already have 4 aces. And we think of deck as 36 places to place sequence of length 4. So we get 36-4+1 ways to place 4 subsequent aces in a deck of 36 cards.

Comment: @DoctorMoisha: No, that does not work. There are many more ways to place four cards than that... unless you mean the four cards must be consecutive ones from the deck, such as 1st,2nd,3rd,4th, through 33rd,34th,35th,36th. If that is your meaning, then there are $33$ ways. If you allow others combinations such as 1st, 5th, 15th, 22nd, there are many more.

Comment: @RoryDaulton I have read your profile and would like to have a (short) chat with you. However, I do not know how to accomplish that (yet).

Comment: @RoryDaulton Would you be so kind to go to chat and to enter the room called Sanctuary?

Comment: @drhab: This is a bad time for me. I have much preparation to do for my school teaching tomorrow, including grading a test. Perhaps another time.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Okay. We will see. There is no hurry at all.